# Naming convention for passing a hash reference to a subroutine

Tags: perl, naming-conventions

When I pass a hash reference to a subroutine, what is a good naming convention for the variable to which the hash ref parameter is assigned?

In the example below, what is the better option:

1. Use the same variable name as the original variable (and let Perl hide the original within the block).
2. Come up with a new name for the hash ref within the subroutine?

I am inclined to use option 1, because a new name for the same hash reference feels redundant.

If option 2 is better, what would be a good naming convention for the variable within the subroutine ?

```
## example:

use strict;
use warnings;

my $href_phone_book = generate_phone_book();
my $phone_number = get_phone_number($href_phone_book, "john");

print $phone_number."\n";

sub generate_phone_book {

    my %phone_book = (

        john => "5554321",
        alice => "5551234"
    );

    return \%phone_book;
}

sub get_phone_number{

    # Is it OK to hide the original variable
    my $href_phone_book = shift;
    # Or should I use a new variable name? What would then be a good naming convention?

    my $person = shift;
    my $phone_number = $href_phone_book->{$person};

    return $phone_number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your variables for the data that they reference. Ideally you should use a short non-ambiguous name, and remove context where possible. For example if your function did something that would apply generically to any hash reference, the name `$hash_ref` would be preferable IMO to `$phone_book`

**1. Use the same variable name as the original variable (and let Perl hide the original within the block).**

Although not a generically safe assumption, it *is* what I would do in your example. I would use `$phone_book` as the single param.

Note if you are using the same reference data structure repeatedly as a parameter to functions, then it points to writing some OO Perl. You should probably create a class, with the data structure the object, and functions changed to instance methods.

Caveat: Your example script will generate a warning due to variable scope. So my advice needs to be modified. I would not alter the subroutine's variable but instead name the global variable something like `$main_phone_book` . . . but this is only necessary due to the structure of your example script. Ideally you should avoid global data structures, and use modularisation (a `PhoneBook.pm` file that contained all the logic for handling phone numbers, whether exported functions or a new class, would not have a clash on the variable name because of package namespaces). Or if the variables are truly global to the problem at hand you probably would not be passing them as parameters at all.

**2. Come up with a new name for the hash ref within the subroutine?**

In this case it is only necessary due to file structure of the example script. Consistency, at least at the level of individual scripts and modules, is more important than finding some special naming convention that can handle all your needs.

---

I suggest you read the variable naming convention chapters of [Perl Best Practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Best_Practices). It is very clear and useful advice.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using .pm files to make distribution of the script easier. Though the variables are not truly global I get from your answer that it is better to use two variable names ($main_phone_book in the global scope and $phone_book within the subroutine block).

Comment: By the way, in my case the example does not give a variable scope warning. Using perl 5.10.1 with use strict and warnings

Comment: @edv: Yes, I would use two variables, with the first, global one having the more complex name. Even if Perl is happy with the reassigned name, I'd suggest you have different names where there is a chance that you confuse yourself about which is which during development or maintenance. Your `$href_phone_book` in the question is OK by the way - not something I would complain about if I saw it in code review (although of course I prefer my own style :-). You can use packages in a single `.pl` file as well, although you do need to worry more than about order of code execution.

Comment: you could just put the global code *after* all the subroutines; if you do not intend to ever have closures, that may be more accident-safe anyway.